# Is there any other network layer protocol other than IP ? If it so ,whether is it applied anywhere?

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet

Have anybody worked or seen any layer 3 protocol other than IP in ethernet communication between two computers???

Comment: @Chenmunka I wanted to know why world is stuck with IP and why cant we replace ip?

Comment: I think the question is deeper than the answer we can give you, but the main reason is, in part at least, the over architecture and structure of the network. It is a protocol which works very well and IMO has no sign of getting weak yet (even 4g is switching to IP).

Comment: @Karthik: protocols by definition must be agreed upon, understood, and implemented by a huge number of players in order to work. right now, changing from IP to another internetwork protocol would fragment the internet, leaving wide swaths of it inaccessible to certain kinds of clients. look at all the problems we're having changing to IPv6 (though, those are mostly self inflicted by use of the local MAC and the human-unfriendly address).

Comment: @FrankThomas : Thank you.I understand the difficulties. But we should always question the convention to learn it better.Shouldn't we?

Comment: @Karthik If you're having to ask this question, then you shouldn't be questioning the norm

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are a few at layer 3

IPv4/IPv6, Internet Protocol
DVMRP, Distance Vector Multicast Routing Protocol
ICMP, Internet Control Message Protocol
IGMP, Internet Group Management Protocol
PIM-SM, Protocol Independent Multicast Sparse Mode
PIM-DM, Protocol Independent Multicast Dense Mode
IPsec, Internet Protocol Security
IPX, Internetwork Packet Exchange
RIP, Routing Information Protocol
DDP, Datagram Delivery Protocol
RSMLT Routed-SMLT
ARP, Address Resolution Protocol

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer

Answer (score 4):

historically there have been lots of them, including NCP (RIP 1980), IPX/SPX (RIP 1999), AppleTalk (who cares), DECNet (RIP 1995), etc. There are also many protocol stacks that use a custom L3, despite being application layer protocls (RIP, OSPF, BGP, (E)IGRP). IIRC IBM Mainframes used the SNA network stack to translate to and from IP, making it a layer 3 protocol.

[Wikipedia has a *List of network protocols* article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_%28OSI_model%29#Layer_3_protocols_.28Network_Layer_management.29)

Most non-IP stacks are used to translate older proprietary network protocols to IP, so anywhere you have a Mainframe or other old system, there is almost gaurenteed to be some protocol translation at play.